# Apply Changes to a web page using Chrome & Inspect Element

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I find myself changing the css & html values of a particular webpage repeatedly to make the page better suited to my screen size. For example, I change the height and width of a div and remove certain elements. When I close the window and reopen it, I have to apply the said changes again. Is  there a way to load a css snippet automatically or make the changes to the page whenever the page is loaded without having to manually make the changes using Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: For custom CSS code you can use 'Chrome Stylist' extension :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options:

- [userChrome.css](https://superuser.com/a/594346/206921) to save CSS snippets
- [bookmarklets](http://www.webreference.com/js/column35/protocol.html) to save JavaScript snippets
- [Content scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) for HTML,CSS, and JavaScript