# How can I make chrome's white flash when a new tab is opened be black?

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever I open a new tab, which is very often, there's a white flash. This is a blinding to my eyes since I often use my computer with dark backgrounds and in low brightness. Is there a way I can change this to a black flash?

There are similar questions here:

- [Prevent white screen before loading page in chromium?](https://superuser.com/questions/580228/prevent-white-screen-before-loading-page-in-chromium)
- [Google Chrome - Override White Blank page between webpage loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243105/google-chrome-override-white-blank-page-between-webpage-loads)

But, the solutions don't work for opening new tabs.

Comment: I don't have a bright screen in front of me. Most of the websites I browse aren't completely white, the programs I use aren't bright, I use low brightness on all of my devices, and I use f.lux.

Comment: I looked around for a solution, suggestions seems to vary but my guess is that this white background is hardcoded into chrome, it'll always appear before calling the theme or extention data. I guess we can't change this without finding a way to hack chrome source code and that's very bad. Dark themes and some other extensions will style the new tab dark but it'll always flash white for a sec.

Comment: What about inverting all computer colors while using chrome? On Windows, you can start the screen magnifier and then press Ctrl-Alt-i to invert the colors.  Look [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/invert-colors-computer-43975.html).

Comment: Anyone found a solution to this issue? User Styles does not work for this particular issue.

Comment: related? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=853986

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Solution provided here: [Chrome's "White Flash" Problem](http://jollo.org/LNT/public/chrome-white-flash.html)

It's a hackish workaround but as you can see in the picture, it works.

Comment: Thanks! From that link: update (march 15, 2017): the white flash bug (issue 470669) has been marked fixed.. 

FYI this bug will be fixed in the stable channel with Chrome 59, which will be released in about 12 weeks. In the meantime you will be able to see it in Canary within a day, or Dev within a week.

Comment: The issue has returned again in 2018. New bug was filed (issue 853986) https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=853986

Comment: Here is a link to gdip_all because the link in the solution doesn't work. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Drugoy/Autohotkey-scripts-.ahk/master/Libraries/Gdip_All.ahk

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution is to hack the chrome source code and compile it.

Fixed the white flash [here](https://github.com/hbtlabs/chromium-white-flash-fix).

Answer (score 3):

If you are still experiencing problem, it may be due to your Google background. If when you open a new tab and Google is the new tab's default location, go to the bottom right of the tab page. Click on the button there, it may say "customize" or it will be an icon. Then select "No background". This solved my problem as the white screen was due to it loading the theme.

Comment: In the "Customize" popup for me it was in "Color and theme", then i could remove a weird dark v3 version, and select a default dark, its much better now. Flashes on opening links and tabs are mostly gone, still experiencing slight flashes sporadically.

Comment: This solution doesnt work anymore at the time of this comment.

Answer (score 2):

[Care your eyes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/care-your-eyes/fidmpnedniahpnkeomejhnepmbdamlhl?hl=en)

This is an extension for google chrome. It allows you to change the background color of webpages at night. It even has an auto mode that will change at a certain time. Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Oh lol I just realized how old this is

Comment: It was recently removed from the store

Answer (score 2):

chrome://flags -> search for dark mode -> set to enabled. Fixed it for me :)

Comment: This answer does indeed help with the brief flash when opening new tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in Google Chrome Beta

Version 72.0.3626.81 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)

Comment: I still see it in Chromium 80, (Ubuntu). Isit really fixed on Chromium or other Oses?

Answer (score 1):

How comes that Google which is the Pinnacle of Web Technology still haven't address a solution to this (incommensurable) annoying issue in 2023?? (Dark theming exists for a reason! Google Wake Up!)

But here's my temporary solution :

If you type `chrome://flags` in your search bar and search for `dark` in the opening page you can activate an experimental feature that will blacken pages and this "white flash" won't appear anymore again. May your eyes heal as you trying to reach a bright future.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is to my understanding no general solution, but I found a sneaky solution yesterday after 2h of hard work.
Just install one of the extensions (or both, doesn't matter I think):

"Black New Tab Page"

"Blank Dark New Tab Page"

Then at least the opening of a new empty tab with STRG+t works without a flash.

hope is helpful, greetings from Siena

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I think chrome will never fix that problem, the only way that can be fixed is if you can open new tabs in background.
Now install this extension :
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clean-crxmouse-gestures/mjidkpedjlfnanainpdfnedkdlacidla

The name of extension is Clean Crx Mouse Gesture

After you install the extension all you have to do is Enable Background tabs from option menu of extension and done.Enjoy[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vx0g.png)

Answer (score -2):

I have a good solution 
Use "opera browser" and "dark mode extension" it works very good if you disable the option in "Advanced settings" named "Delay loading of background tabs"