# Chrome disable white blank page flash before website is loaded

Tags: google-chrome

When going to a new webpage in Chrome, the screen will flash white before the website is loaded. This is annoying as I have a lot of websites set to use dark themes with Stylish and the transition is like a blinding flashbang. Is there any way to disable it or change the flash to black?

I have tried these solutions and they did not work for me:

[Google Chrome - Override White Blank page between webpage loads [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243105/google-chrome-override-white-blank-page-between-webpage-loads)

[Prevent white screen before loading page in chromium?](https://superuser.com/questions/580228/prevent-white-screen-before-loading-page-in-chromium)

Comment: Duplicate of [Prevent white screen before loading page in chromium?](https://superuser.com/questions/580228/prevent-white-screen-before-loading-page-in-chromium?)

Answer (score -2):

If this just recently started, you might try uninstalling Chrome, deleting the Google folder in Program Files(x86) and reinstall Chrome.  This usually will fix issues like that.