# Start Chrome in kiosk mode with black background instead of white

Tags: google-chrome, embedded, kiosk

For an embedded project, when starting Chrome in kiosk mode, just after boot:

```
chrome.exe --kiosk http://127.0.0.1/index.html
```

there is a 500 ms delay before the site is displayed, during which Chrome displays a blank white screen, which is kind of "flashing" because before, the screen is black, and then, the site has a black background.

**Is there a way to set a black background of the Chrome interface, in kiosk mode?**

Edit: related: https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/squ71r/how_can_disable_this_white_flash_when_opening/

Comment: check out [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/580228/prevent-white-screen-before-loading-page-in-chromium). Chrome does not support user's stylesheet anymore, but [Firefox does](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/contributors-guide-firefox-advanced-customization) if it is a valid option for you to change browser.

Comment: I wonder if an acceptable workaround is to start Chrome minimized, then to maximize it after x seconds programmatically since it seems that that initial white flash you see is not possible to change. So just an idea for a workaround if that is indeed the case but I have not tested or know the logic but I suspect something like this is possible from the technical side somehow and someway. Or start initial minimized, then load kiosk, then kill minimized session or something like that.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle It could be possible, but I did some tests, and it seems impossible to start Chrome *in kiosk mode* minimized. It's important to keep `--kiosk` mode for my application (it adds many features to limit the device for the end user on a public computer).

Comment: How about if you have a separate already opened and minimized chrome session keeping track of PID, then opening a new kiosk mode Chrome instance, does the kiosk mode session still have the initial white screen? This way kiosk is a separate session, then once it is up, you then kill the pid of the other session or use some other technique. Not sure if that's what you tested or not but I was thinking about something like that. I totally get the importance of kiosk mode configurations, just never noticed the initial thing you are mentioning here in those systems (not very many in my case though).

Comment: Another thought, would be to try to load kiosk from a Chrome profile with the dark extensions and backgrounds enabled, so ensure it logs into that profile with the kiosk mode configuration (not default). If you can pass chrome the specific profile and kiosk command line arguments? Not sure if that'd make any difference but something else to test just in case. Not sure what specific Chrome extensions you are using, but might be one out there that does not have the initialization issue.

Comment: Thanks @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I think this has been tested in https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/squ71r/how_can_disable_this_white_flash_when_opening/, but sadly no real solution yet. The only solution would be to recompile `libGLESv2` . See also https://github.com/hbtlabs/chromium-white-flash-fix, but unfortunately this is abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

There has been much written about this white flash for a new tab.
Some writers even blame Windows display mechanisms rather than Chrome.

Below are some suggestions :

- In `chrome://flags/`, enable the option of `enable-force-dark`
- Use the extension
  [Blank Dark New Tab Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blank-dark-new-tab-page/agldajbhchobfgjcmmigehfdcjbmipne)
- Use the extension
  [Black New Tab Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/black-new-tab-page/anoeoicpaambkpaglbpghmjkhellkgld)
- You could try another browser. Some reports say that Firefox
  and Vivaldi do not have this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tested the three first solutions, but there is still a white flash on Chrome startup. I'll continue searching :)

Comment: As Vivaldi is built using Chromium (but different from Chrome), if it truly doesn't have this problem it might be a suitable replacement.